# Cross Domain Request - page content with all scripts executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

The title describes my problem quite good.

I try to do a cross domain request, where the loaded content is executed first.

So I have page www.xyz.com which loads some page content via ajax (for example a live ticker) and I'd like to use this content in my own file. Since Php can't execute anything I'd like to do a jquery get request but I can't figure out how to get both at the same time, cross domain request and executed javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Update:

For example I tried this code:

```
function requestCrossDomain( site, callback ) {

    if ( !site ) {
        alert('No site was passed.');
        return false;
    }

    var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="' + site + '"') + '&format=xml&callback=?';

    $.getJSON( yql, cbFunc );

    function cbFunc(data) {

    if ( data.results[0] ) {

        data = data.results[0];

        if ( typeof callback === 'function') {
            callback(data);
        }
    }
    else throw new Error('Nothing returned from getJSON.');
    }
}

requestCrossDomain('http://www.google.com', function(results) {
    //htmlcode = eval(results); 
    htmlcode = results; 
    $('#container').html(htmlcode);
});
```

Comment: Help me understand.  When you say "use this content in my own file", do you mean a javascript file or a PHP file?

Comment: I don't realy care - but since you can't execute js with php and there is no external service (as far as i know)  which does this, it's a javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must use AJAX to grab a file, then try to execute it, you can do so with the following code:

```
eval(ajaxResponseText);
```

Another way to do this is to generate a  tag from an XHR taking advantage of the `data` URI scheme.

```
var script = document.createElement("script")
script.src = "data:text/javascript;charset=utf8," + encodeURIComponent(ajaxResponseText);
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

**EDIT**

Now that there is an example illuminating your question, I must amend my answer.

You *cannot* make a Cross-Origin request using ajax on just about all browsers without abiding by the CORS specification because of the prevalence and severity of cross-origin attacks. The **Cross Origin Resource Sharing** specification allows you to make ajax requests to a different origin so long as the new origin permits it. If it is not working, the javascript console might be a good place to look for errors.